# jQuery upgrading .data from old code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some old code that I have to update which is using 1.3.2 and it's using the `.data()` method. Im trying to update this to the latest version of jQuery.

Accordingly, I'm a bit confused [new to jQuery] as it's using

```
    if (jQuery('#id').data(dataCollection)) {
        //do Stuff
    }
```

When I use `console.log` to debug it just says `undefined` ?

Any idea's how I can go about fixing this? I'm assuming it was relying on it returning the `id` - I read somewhere that this changed > 1.3.2? How would I go about updating the above to get the ID?

Comment: What is `dataCollection`? Is it a string?

Answer (score 0):

What is dataCollection? It should always be a string.

Your code is trying to see if `#id` has any thing set in the data(dataCollection). If it is not null then it will go inside the `if` condition.

Comment: thanks a lot. I think the problem is that `dataCollection` is `undefined` and I'm unsure how to make it return correctly ? It's an array.

Comment: how would I go about getting the ID instead of the data object ?

Comment: Are you trying to set this array into `#id`?

Comment: yeah I think this is what the code is doing. i.e. under 1.3.2 - the `data(dataCollection)` returned an ID - now instead it returns the data object ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you post some markup and how you get the dataCollection?